# is spring batch supports parquet file reading and writing

Tags: java, spring-batch, parquet

I want to read parquet file in java using apache-parquet but lack of knowledge and documentation available on internet not able to achive it.

trying to find if spring batch supports the parquet file reading and writing ?

i have already tried to read using apache parquet library.

Comment: There is no built-in support for parquet. You need to create a custom item reader/writer for this format.

Comment: thank you. I found mainly two ways to read parquet in java -https://parquet.apache.org/ by using this library but seems no more support available for this library also, second is by using spark which needs setup of spark to run program. is there any other way do you know?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr is still maintained.